# Remove file if it exists

Tags: haskell

What is the right way of doing this in Haskell?

```
if exists "foo.txt" then delete "foo.txt"
doSomethingElse
```

So far I have:

```
import System.Directory
main = do
        filename <- getFileNameSomehow
        fileExists <- doesFileExist filename
        if fileExists 
             then removeFile filename
             ???
        doSomethingElse
```

Comment: The `doesFileExist` function is really an invitation to race conditions.  It should not exist.

Comment: @augustss: How about we just rename it to `didFileExistLastTimeIChecked`?

Comment: I suggest `didFileNotNeverExist`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You would be better off removing the file and simply recovering if it does not exist:

```
import Prelude hiding (catch)
import System.Directory
import Control.Exception
import System.IO.Error hiding (catch)

removeIfExists :: FilePath -> IO ()
removeIfExists fileName = removeFile fileName `catch` handleExists
  where handleExists e
          | isDoesNotExistError e = return ()
          | otherwise = throwIO e
```

This avoids the race condition of someone deleting the file between your code checking whether it exists and deletes it. It might not matter in your case, but it's good practice anyway.

Note the `import Prelude hiding (catch)` line — this is because the Prelude contains older functions from exception handling which are now deprecated in favour of Control.Exception, which also has a function named `catch`; the import line simply hides the Prelude's `catch` in favour of [Control.Exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html)'s.

However, that still leaves your more fundamental underlying question: how do you write conditionals in `IO`?

Well, in this case, it would suffice to simply do

```
when fileExists $ removeFile filename
```

(using [Control.Monad.when](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3awhen)). But it's helpful here, as it usually is in Haskell, to look at the types.

Both branches of a conditional must have the same type. So to fill in

```
if fileExists
    then removeFile filename
    else ???
```

we should look at the type of `removeFile filename`; whatever `???` is, it has to have the same type.

[System.Directory.removeFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/latest/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v%3aremoveFile) has the type `FilePath -> IO ()`, so `removeFile filename` has the type `IO ()`. So what we want is an IO action with a result of type `()` that does nothing.

Well, the purpose of `return` is to construct an action that has no effects, and just returns a constant value, and `return ()` has the right type for this: `IO ()` (or more generally, `(Monad m) => m ()`). So `???` is `return ()` (which you can see I used in my improved snippet above, to do nothing when `removeFile` fails because the file doesn't exist).

(By the way, you should now be able to implement `when` with the help of `return ()`; it's really simple :))

Don't worry if you find it hard to get into the Haskell way of things at first — it'll come naturally in time, and when it does, it's very rewarding. :)

Comment: Here's a link to Control.Exception's documentation: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html — I couldn't put it in the post because I don't have enough reputation :/

Comment: No problem — as far as reading material goes, there's the excellent [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/), but I imagine you already know about these. I can recommend [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)'s ability to search by type as invaluable for Haskell programming, though.

Comment: I put the link into the text. Nice answer, will help getting you enough rep to put in more than two links yourself :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Nice to see you over here. You're over 100 rep now, so most of the really irritating limitations should be gone. :]

Answer (score 11):

(**Note:** ehird's answer makes a very good point regarding a race condition. It should be kept in mind when reading my answer, which ignores the issue. Do note also that the imperative pseudo-code presented in the question also suffers from the same problem.)

What defines the filename? Is it given in the program, or supplied by the user? In your imperative pseudo-code, it's a constant string in the program. I'll assume you want the user to supply it by passing it as the first command line argument to the program.

Then I suggest something like this:

```
import Control.Monad    
import System.Directory
import System.Environment

doSomethingElse :: IO ()

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  fileExists <- doesFileExist (head args)
  when fileExists (removeFile (head args))
  doSomethingElse
```

(As you can see, I added the type signature of `doSomethingElse` to avoid confusion).

I import `System.Environment` for the `getArgs` function. In case the file in question is simply given by a constant string (such as in your imperative pseudo-code), just remove all the args stuff and fill in the constant string wherever I have `head args`.

`Control.Monad` is imported to get the `when` function. Note that this useful function is *not* a keyword (like `if`), but an ordinary function. Let's look at its type:

```
when :: Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m ()
```

In your case `m` is `IO`, so you can think of `when` as a function that takes a `Bool` and an IO action and performs the action only if the `Bool` is `True`. Of course you could solve your problem with `if`s, but in your case `when` reads a lot clearer. At least I think so.

**Addendum:** If you, like I did at first, get the feeling that `when` is some magical and difficult machinery, it's very instructive to try to define the function yourself. I promise you, it's dead simple...

Comment: It's also instructive to think about *why* it's simple to define `when`, and what other implications that has. Imperative code blocks are first-class entities in Haskell in a way that few languages can match.