# Unix domain socket file still present after closing it

Tags: sockets, unix, unix-socket

This is what I'm trying in `ghci` (Haskell `REPL`):

```
>>> import Network.Socket
>>> sock <- socket AF_UNIX Stream defaultProtocol
>>> bind sock (SockAddrUnix "./test.socket")
>>> listen sock 5
>>> close sock
```

At this point `./test.socket` is in the file system refusing connections, but I'd expect that after closing a listening connection the file would also be removed. I believe this is standard Unix convention, not specific to Haskell, so what's the reason to have the file lying around after closing it?

**Update:** If I try to bind another socket to the same file I get an error:

```
>>> sock2 <- socket AF_UNIX Stream defaultProtocol
>>> bind sock (SockAddrUnix "./test.socket")
*** Exception: bind: resource busy (Address already in use)
```

So if I can't rebind another socket to the file or reconnect to it because it's closed what's the point?

**Update:** The [man entry for `unix`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) mentions:

> Binding to a socket with a filename creates a socket in the filesystem
>   that **must be deleted** by the caller when it is no longer needed (using
>   unlink(2)).  The usual UNIX close-behind semantics apply; the socket
>   can be unlinked at any time and will be finally removed from the
>   filesystem when the last reference to it is closed.

So it's expected from the user to `unlink` explicitly the socket, but that still doesn't answer my question. What's the reason to have it around if you can't do anything with the socket?

Is my high level programming bias kicking in here? Is this kind of explicitness the norm when doing systems level programming?

Comment: @wildplasser I can't bind to the same file system object... I updated the question.

Comment: `Exception: bind: resource busy (Address already in use)` only one process at a time can bind to an address. Probably another process already has it in use.

Comment: I can't find any process using the sockets (`ss -aA unix`). Even after a system reboot I keep getting the same error.

Comment: For unix domain sockets you should use `ss -l -a -funix` (or just plain old netstat -a)

Comment: @wildplasser you can't listen on a pre-existing unix domain socket regardless of whether or not there's another process currently using it.

Comment: @JeremyList: You are right. I must have been confusing them with named pipes. Also: mknod(1) does not support unix-domain sockets, they are created automically by the socket() call. ... Removing the comment ...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this

```
createSocket :: FilePath -> IO Socket
createSocket path = do
  removeIfExists path
  sock <- socket AF_UNIX Stream 0
  bind sock $ SockAddrUnix path
  return sock

removeIfExists :: FilePath -> IO ()
removeIfExists fileName = removeLink fileName `catch` handleExists
  where handleExists e
          | isDoesNotExistError e = return ()
          | otherwise = throwIO e
```

**UPDATE:** closing a socket:

```
closeSocket :: Socket -> IO ()
closeSocket sock = do
  name <- getSocketName sock
  close sock
  case name of
    SockAddrUnix path -> removeIfExists path
    _ -> return ()
```

Comment: If you looked into mysql sources (for example), you would see that mysqld also deletes socket file.

Comment: Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502201/remove-file-if-it-exists/8502391#8502391 :-)